# How to read files in sequence via filebeat

Tags: filebeat

Now I have 10 log files to be read by Filebeat, assume that they are log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt, ... log10.txt. I want Filebeat to read them one by one,it means at most there can be 1 harvester reading. So, I set the following settings in the filebeat.yml for my filestream input:
[image]

The result is, Filebeat can read only 1 file because I verified the documents in my Elasticsearch output, the documents are from one certain file only. It seems once Filebeat closed the harvester for one file, it will not automatically switch to harvest the next file, but just closed the harvester.

I'm not sure whether this is because I did not configure correctly. I think Filebeat should continue to read the next file once it finished reading one file after 5 second, as I configured the close.on_state_change.inactive there.

So, I am asking whether we can control Filebeat to read multiple log files in sequence, rather than starting one harvester for one file.

I tried to set harvester_limit: 1 and close.on_state_change.inactive: 5s, expecting Filebeatto start only one harvester to read my log files, if it finished reading one file, it should automatically shipped to read another file, until all log files are read.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, I believe there is a [bug](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/34342) in filestream which causes harvester_limit to work unexpectedly.

In the meantime you could set input type to log and use following config options;

```
scan.sort: filename
scan.order: asc
harvester_limit: 1
close_timeout: 5s
```

Test what close_timeout value works for you.